# How to run iTunes with Wine once installed

Tags: wine, itunes

I successfully followed the instructions I found online for installing Wine, configuring it to run as Windows 10, and downloading/running the iTunes installer .EXE file. However, post-installation I cannot find how to run iTunes. It does not appear in my application menu, and when I search for 'itunes' on my disk, the only things which appear are two .DESKTOP files. These don't run anything when clicked on, they just open in a text editor. They contain what appears to be an executable line, but when I copy it into the terminal and run it I get an error from Wine saying "failed to open" followed by an incomplete Windows-style path string. The only thing I can think of is that I un-checked the "create desktop icon" box when installing, but when I uninstall and re-install I no longer have the option to check or uncheck this box. It also seems unlikely to me that this would be the issue, as it should only affect the creation of a symbolic link in the Desktop directory, right?

What am I doing wrong?

Using Ubuntu 22.04.3